# How to make sublime text - latexing to automatically close left braces inside math env?

Tags: auto-completion, sublime-text

In sublime text 3, using latexing whenever I am inside math mode ($ ... $), if I start typing $v_{$, this left brace doesn't close automatically. How can I fix this?

Moreover, is there a way by which I can make the editor to add {} every time I type _ or ^ ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be [a known issue](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7889)...

Answer (score 2):

The Sublime Text package [LateXYZ](https://github.com/randy3k/LaTeXYZ) can deal with this super smoothly.

You can install it through the Package manager.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a old question, but the problem still exists (as of March 2017). The package LatexTools does not fix this issue, but the package LatexBox (which used to be called LatexPlus) does solve it. That is one of the reasons I keep both of them installed on sublime.